# Limit of the spectrum in Banach algebra

Tags: spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ an unital complex Banach algebra, $a_{n} $ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=a$. What is the relation between $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sigma(a_{n})$ and $\sigma(a)$. I think that it could be $\sigma(a)\subset \lim_{n\to \infty}\sigma(a_{n}) $. But it is just a hope. I would appreciate someone help.

Comment: Invertible elements form an open such in in A, and inversion is continuous on this open set. So, if $e$ is a unit and $(\lambda e-a)$ is invertible for some scalar $\lambda$, then the same is true for $(\lambda e -a_{n})$ for large enough $n$. Have you tried looking at that? What have you tried?